# Java autogenerated getters-setters in project - best practice

Tags: java, jaxb, dto

Our project has started newly and wanted to know some of the best practices followed in industry. We have generated lot of DTOs(getters and setters) code for webservices using JaxB. we keep all the DTO classes along with regular pojos(logic written), its looks like large project due to this auto-generated code, also for code coverage it considers these classes also.
I am keen to know that these classes should be as a jar file in classpath or it should be as classes in project.
Thanks in Advance,
Madhavi

Answer (score 2):

If your project uses Maven (or something similar) I would advise having the code generation and the generated code in a separate module of a multi module project.

This way the generated stuff is out of the way of the hand crafted code. You can also set up your Maven build process to then build this module first and the rest of the code can rely on the resulting artefact, be it a jar or something else.

You could also regenerate the generated code on each new build this way. Although this can be a lengthy process, depending on the service.

Answer (score 1):

Generated files should not be mixed with your written files.

A common approach is to generate them to the `target` folder, e.g. `target/generated-sources` or something similiar. Of course, if they are rarely changed, you could also put them in a `jar` file that you import into your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to keep them in jar. As its auto generated code and no one is supposed to change.  Whenever regenerated include new jar.